# How to split a Listings table

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, titletoc, split

I would like to split \lstlistoflistings into two lists (one in the main contents of the document, one in the appendices).
Titletoc only works for figures / tables : is there a workaround for that ?

My structure currently looks like this :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% Start partial lists
\startlist[main]{lol}% starts main list of listings

% ... Some contents + printlist somewhere here

% Stop partial lists
\stoplist[main]{lol}% stops main list of listings

% Start partial lists
\startlist[appendices]{lol}% starts appendices list of listings

\begin{appendices}
    % ... some listings here + printlist somewhere here
\end{appendices}

% Stop partial lists
\stoplist[appendices]{lol}% stops appendices list of listings
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a ugly solution using no other packages

```
\makeatletter

  \providecommand{\phantomsection}{}
  % Pour modifier plus facilement le nom - Ici, je recycles ceux de base
  \newcommand\appendixlistingname{\lstlistlistingname}
  \newcommand{\listofappendixlistings}{%
  % Applying the same trick as listings does with \lstlistoflistings: Modifying \@starttoc such that it can load only .apl files
    \begingroup
      \let\@starttoc@orig\@starttoc%
      \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\appendixlistingname}
      \renewcommand{\@starttoc}[1]{%
        \@starttoc@orig{apl}%
      }%    
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixlistingname}
      \tableofcontents% Calling \tableofcontents with the `.apl` file instead of `.toc`
    \endgroup
  }

  \newcommand{\appendixFix}{%
  \setcounter{lstlisting}{0}%
  \@ifundefined{theHlstlisting}{%
    }{%
      \renewcommand{\theHlstlisting}{appendix}
    }%
  \write\@auxout{%
    \string\let\string\latex@tf@lol\string\tf@lol% Store the original `\tf@lol` file handle
    \string\let\string\tf@lol\string\tf@apl% 
  }%
}{}{}

\makeatother
```

which can be used as

```
\appendixFix

\begin{appendices}
   \listofappendixlistings
   \input{sections/appendixes/index} % File containing some listings code
\end{appendices}
```